# Specify table for Row_Number() in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, window-functions

I have the following query that is currently working as intended. It's joining my table onto itself in order to identify records that have had a status change.

```
from
    (select
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by OBJECTID, GDB_TO_DATE DESC) as R_NUM,
            OBJECTID,
            STATUS, 
            GDB_TO_DATE
        from updm.pipes_h
    ) r1
    join
    (select
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by OBJECTID, GDB_TO_DATE DESC) as R_NUM,
            OBJECTID,
            STATUS,
            GDB_TO_DATE
        from updm.pipes_h
    ) r2 on r1.R_NUM = r2.R_NUM+1
    where r1.objectid = r2.objectid
    and r1.status != r2.status;
```

However, I am trying to add an additional join for some more information from another table. I want to place this join inside my r1 table like so:

```
select *
from
    (select
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by p.OBJECTID, p.GDB_TO_DATE DESC) as R_NUM,
            p.OBJECTID,
            p.STATUS, 
            p.GDB_TO_DATE,
            ps.PRESSURESYSTEMNAME
        from updm.pipes_h p
        join updm.pressuresystem ps ON p.PRESSURESYSTEM_GLOBALID = ps.globalid
    ) r1
    join ...
```

The problem is if I do this, the query returns incorrectly. I'm not sure what's wrong here, although I suspect it's the ROW_NUMBER() function in r1. I tried using p.ROW_NUMBER() but this wasn't correct syntax either. Can anyone advise? I've tried looking up examples of ROW_NUMBER() and didn't find one where it was used in conjunction with a join.

Comment: Where is your `select` clause?

Answer (score 2):

You original query is overcomplicating things. Just use `lag()` (or `lead()`):

```
select * 
from (
    select
        objectid,
        status,
        gbd_to_date,
        lag(objectid) over(order by objectid, gdb_to_date desc) lag_objectid
    from updm.pipes_h
) p
where objectid <> lag_objectid
```

If you want to bring an additional table, you have to be cautious; your explanation suggest that you don't have a 1-1 relationship between the current and new table: so rows from the original table are likely being duplicated or evicted, which changes the partition over wich the window function operates. It might be simpler to join in the outer query instead:

```
select *  -- better enumerate the columns here than use "*"
from (
    select
        objectid,
        status,
        gbd_to_date,
        lag(objectid) over(order by objectid, gdb_to_date desc) lag_objectid,
        pressuresystem_globalid 
    from updm.pipes_h
) p
join updm.pressuresystem ps ON p.pressuresystem_globalid = ps.globalid
where objectid <> lag_objectid
```

Comment: I looked at the lag function for my purposes, however, I opted for the join because I wanted to bring in the previous row's GBD_TO_DATE and STATUS as additional columns for the same record. This query is feeding a report that I'm building in PowerBI, and it would be easier for me for me to have the change from the previous on the same line. I couldn't find a way to do this with lag, is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @RuoxiGuo: you can add more `lag()` expressions. For example, `lag(status) over(order by objectid, gdb_to_date desc)` gives you the previous `status`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I'll give it a shot when I get to work on Monday! I think I fundamentally misunderstood how lag() works. (Side note, I'm not sure why I wasn't able to @ you properly sorry if you got spammed)

Comment: Hey, I just really wanted to thank you! I finally got some time to toggle with this query today and it's working great. It's very simple to understand and it's helpful to see how you built this because I don't really have a good grasp of SQL structure at the moment. I had tried to implement a couple of other ways to do this prior to posting here but I think this is definitely my favorite. Thank you! (My @ are still not working)